# Localhost not recognized in windows 7 machine

Tags: asp.net, iis, localhost, port

I have IIS installed on my windows 7 machine.

But when I try to browse the localhost I am getting 404.

I tried to put netstat and I see

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State 
 TCP    127.0.0.1:80           ABCHOME:49466        TIME_WAIT
 TCP    127.0.0.1:80           ABCHOME:49468        TIME_WAIT
```

ABCHOME is the computer name. Any idea how to find what is that foreign address and how can I stop listening to port 80?

I tried uninstall and reinstall the IIS but no luck.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I already have the following entry in host file 127.0.0.1 localhost

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other Web Server installed? This may sound ridiculous but I was getting the same error once, I forgot I had Apache installed as well.

Comment: I don't have any other Web server on this machine.

Comment: Just a thought, check your hosts file in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc for any weird loop back lines.

Comment: Nothing is there in the host file, everything was commented. So I added 127.0.0.1 localhost but still no luck

Answer (score 2):

The foreign address is simply your own machine trying to reach itself. The port is semi-random, grabbed from a pool of available ports by the browser.

To change IIS listening port from 80 try : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149605

> "Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.0
>
> Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager. Select the Web site
>   that you wish to configure. In the Action pane, click Bindings. Click
>   Add to add a new site binding, or click Edit to change an existing
>   binding. Click OK to apply the changes."